# Need Help in using preg_split() in php

Tags: php

Can anyone explain how to use preg_split() function to split below mentioned string

```
String  [ 

date=2017-05-31 time=14:12:05 devname=FGT3HD3914801291 devid=FGT3HD3914801449 logid=0316013056 type=utm subtype=webfilter eventtype=ftgd_blk level=warning vd="root" policyid=63 sessionid=9389050 user="" srcip=172.30.10.90 srcport=53542 srcintf="port5" dstip=50.7.146.50 dstport=80 dstintf="port2" proto=6 service=HTTP hostname="noblockweb.org" profile="IT ADMIN" action=blocked reqtype=direct url="/wpad.dat?1925450516382f9869bdfee527b429fb23737930" sentbyte=126 rcvdbyte=325 direction=outgoing msg="URL belongs to a denied category in policy" method=domain cat=55 catdesc="Meaningless Content" crscore=10 crlevel=medium

]
```

I need output in following structure 
Array
(
    [0] => date=2017-05-31
    [1] => time=14:12:05
     .
     .
     .
     .
    [20]=> msg="URL belongs to a denied category in policy"
     .
     .
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

preg_split is maybe not the right tool for this. You can better use `preg_match_all` for this kind of splitting.

```
<?php

    $str = 'date=2017-05-31 time=14:12:05 devname=FGT3HD3914801291 devid=FGT3HD3914801449 logid=0316013056 type=utm subtype=webfilter eventtype=ftgd_blk level=warning vd="root" policyid=63 sessionid=9389050 user="" srcip=172.30.10.90 srcport=53542 srcintf="port5" dstip=50.7.146.50 dstport=80 dstintf="port2" proto=6 service=HTTP hostname="noblockweb.org" profile="IT ADMIN" action=blocked reqtype=direct url="/wpad.dat?1925450516382f9869bdfee527b429fb23737930" sentbyte=126 rcvdbyte=325 direction=outgoing msg="URL belongs to a denied category in policy" method=domain cat=55 catdesc="Meaningless Content" crscore=10 crlevel=medium';

preg_match_all('/ ?(\w+\=(("[^"]*")|([^ ]*)))/',$str,$matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

- ' ?' - match a space character, it is marked as optional by the question mark, because it should also match the first item.
- The parantheses are there for getting the matching parts back and they build blocks of expressions. This first pair of paran is around the part we are interested. Thatswhy `$matches[1]`is used. `$matches[0]` contains the whole matched part, with the possible first space character.
- (...|...) - the bar character means that the part left or right of it could match.
- ("[^"]") - this is for matching quoted strings. `[^"]` means, match everything what is  not a quotation mark ". The square brackets build a class of matching characters. If the caret ^ is the first character in the class, that means the class is inverted.
- ([^ ]*) - everything what is not a space character with possible zero length.